# Bootstrap: высота столбцов

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

На странице использую bootstrap3. Структура некоторой части следующая:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
        <iframe src="..."></iframe>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
        ....
   </div>
</div>
```

То есть в ряду две колонки, в одной из них видео с ютуба во фрейме. Нужно сделать одинаковой высоту колонок ряда, т.е. чтобы при масштабировании высота  фрейма совпадала с высотой содержимого второй колонки. 
Нагуглил свойство `display:flex;`  но мне это не помогло. Прошу помощи в решении этой проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может такой вариант подойдет

```css
.row-table{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.col-table-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.col-table-cell:nth-of-type(1){
    background: #ccc;
}
.col-table-cell:nth-of-type(2){
    background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-table">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-table-cell">
        <iframe src="..."></iframe>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-table-cell">
        ....
   </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/6mrayrgv/)

Comment: Не совсем то, ездит в стороны при масштабировании http://jsfiddle.net/6mrayrgv/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
.row-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

В `row` необходимо добавить еще и `row-flex`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?